# sending POST data with JavaScript (xhttp) (ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, https

```
<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var a = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("message").value;
    var postdata = "name=a&message=b"; //Probably need the escape method for values here, like you did

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "/chat/backend-input.php", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send(postdata);
}
</script>

<form onsubmit="loadDoc()">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
Message: <input type="text" name="message"><br>
<input type="submit"></input>
</form>
```

Why does this code not work? Have I done something wrong, when I press the submit button it does not POST the data from the form

Can someone explain where I have gone wrong?

Edit: Instead of outputting what is in the form it's outputting a and b.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send POST data using XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: you do not cancel the form submission

Comment: Did you take a look at the console? What does it say? ----- Also, add an `id` to `<input type="text" name="message" id="message">`

Comment: I added that ID, I missed it, but it's still not working!

Comment: It is outputting a and b... And not what was in the form

Answer (score 1):

Firtly, don't forget to add the `id="message"` to the line: `Message: <input type="text" name="message" id="message"><br>`.

## Posting data

You do

```
var postdata = "name=a&message=b";
// ...
xhttp.send(postdata);
```

So the values you are posting are effectively `"a"` and `"b"`.

Instead of that, you need to add the values of the `a` and `b` variables to `postdata`. Simple string concatenation would do, but before you need to escape them (using [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)) in case they have special chars.

So, try the following to fix it. **Change**:

```
var postdata = "name=a&message=b";
```

To:

```
var postdata = "name=" + encodeURIComponent(a) + "&message=" + encodeURIComponent(b);
```

And it should work.